# Correct python code needed to remove duplicate lines from outputted text file

Tags: python, duplicates, output, text-files

i have taken data from a text file, converted it into a tuple and processed the elements (using the for loop) and produced a output text file.

The output data is correct except that it has duplicates, triplicates and multiple-copy lines. My imput text file looks like this
[Data for input is taken from this text doc here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LrQ4.png)

[This is the intended output txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhtym.png)

[this is my output text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WulSm.png)

my code is below`

```
myList=[]
with open("data_2.txt") as f: 
    for line in f:
        myList.append(tuple(line.rstrip().split()))
dic = {}
for index, ele in enumerate(myList):
    key=index+1
    val_2=float(ele[1])
    val_3=float(ele[2])
    dic.update({key: (ele[0],val_2,val_3)})
    for i in range(0,len(dic)):
            power= 5//(val_2)
            P=pow(0.5,power)
            cal_grams=val_3*P
            if cal_grams<100:
                outfile = open("Element_Shortage_List.txt", "a")           
                outfile.write(str(ele[0])+ "   " + str(cal_grams) + "\n")
                with open("Element_Shortage_List.txt", 'r') as linremove:
                    words = set(linremove.read().split())
                outfile.close()
```

The above code produces duplicate, triplicate, and in some cases multiple lines of text.
the section of the code that is supposed to remove duplicate lines is

```
with open("Element_Shortage_List.txt", 'r') as linremove:
                words = set(linremove.read().split())
```

but it doesnt seem to work.I have tried writing
`outfile = open("Element_Shortage_List.txt", "a")`
as
`outfile = open("Element_Shortage_List.txt", "w")`
but instead of giving me duplicates it gives me a single line(the last one in the intended output list)

Does anyone know the correct code for multiple-copy line removal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a neat trick (which you are using in some way) to remove duplicates from a list. And that is to convert it first to a **set** and again to a list. It goes something like this: `arr = list( set( arr ) )`. So i can think of two ways to do this.
First, write all you want inside your output file. Read the output file again and add each line to a set. Then, rewrite the set inside the output file. The pseudo-code:

```py
## When you are done writing your output file

my_output_file = open('output file address' , 'r+')
reader = my_output_file.readlines()
reader = list( set(reader) ) 
my_output_file.write(reader)
my_output_file.close()
```

Second, you can cache your output inside a list (not writing it one line at a time), convert the cached output to a set and then write it inside your output file. Pseudo Code:

```py
output_cache = []
with open('address') as file:
   ## when you are done processing the file, instead of writing it
   ## to the output file, cache it
   output_cache.append(my_processed_line)

output_cache = list(set(output_cache))
file = open('address of output' , 'w')
file.write(output_cache)
file.close()
```

Comment: i can get my results that way...could you be more specific